# PUT with jquery returns error

Tags: php, jquery, html, curl, put

I am trying to update a field with a small jquery script but it keeps returning an error and I cannot see where I have a problem.

I have an anchor with onclick="reportAd(MyAid)" that runs this:

```
function reportAd(aid) {
   var conf = confirm("Will you report this ad?");

   if(conf == true) {         
      $.ajax({
         url: rootURL + '/reportad/',
         type: 'PUT',
         dataType: 'json',
         contentType: 'application/json',
         data: {'aid': ''+aid+''},
         success: function(data) {
             alert("Ad have been reported");
         },
         error: function(data) {
             console.log(data);
         }
     });
   }
   return false;
}
```

Which should run this:

```
$app->put('/reportad/', function() use ($app, $adverts) {    
   $request = Slim::getInstance()->request();
   $data = json_decode($request->getBody());

   $adverts->report_ad($data->aid);
});
```

FireBug gives me this:

```
Object { readyState=4, status=200, statusText="OK"}
```

If I call the script with cURL

```
curl -i -X PUT -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"aid":"43"}' http://www.domain.dk/reportad/
```

it works.

Comment: Is rootURL in the same domain ? What's your browser ?

Comment: rootURL is in the same domain, yes. 
Both FF and Chrome gives me the same error.

Comment: What's returned by the server ? Is it valid JSON ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking the content of the answer to be parsed as JSON. If it's not JSON, then you're probably encountering a parseError.

Try to remove the `dataType` argument.

Comment: Removing dataType will return success, but not running my script.

Answer (score 0):

The standard approach to overcome lack of support for "PUT" is to use "POST" and to introduce a pseudo-PUT mechanism, on which the server-side code can branch.

For example :

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: {method: 'PUT', 'aid': ''+aid+''},
});
```

Exactly what you do server-side depends on the language/framework you are using.

Comment: Don't modern browser support PUT methods in XmlHttpRequest ?

Comment: I understand that support is still patchy, at least it was last time I checked.